# CKEditor not saving "align-center" class on paragraph

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have an TYPO3 8.7.27 using CkEditor.

Center alignment works perfectly in editor but gets lost after saving within TYPO3. Before CKEditor I was using HTMLArea. The Center classes on headlines get saved and not stripped.

Any ideas why the classes get stripped from p-Tags only?

Answer (score 1):

I've the exact same problem and looking into it right now.

I've tried following:

```
processing:
  HTMLparser_db:
    tags:
      p:
        allowedAttribs:
          - class
```

But no luck.

--

Update:

I found a solution to my problem, I added following to my Rte.ts

```
# Ensure that text-alignments are not stripped from p-tags
RTE.default.proc.allowedClasses := addToList(text-left,text-center,text-right)
```

But afterwards i saw that following in my Default.yml would also do the trick.

```
processing:
  allowedClasses: ['text-left', 'text-center', 'text-right']
```

This is the link bringing my into this https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82476#note-3 after I found out, during debugging, that my proc.AllowedClasses was empty.

Comment: I don't know if this will help you. It's on div-tags, but the problem sound similar. 

I didn't work for me. But it might trigger some thoughts for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div

Comment: I've tried the 

config.allowedContent: true

but didn't work for me either.

Comment: Is this the case for you? It isn't for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815636/typo3-8-7-9-ckeditor-removes-block-styles-after-save?rq=1